# Is there any way to access the Github API with c++?

Tags: c++, github, github-api

Pretty simple question, but I can't find any c++ libraries for using the github api... I already know how to use it in python, does that help? I am a c/c++ newb.

Thanks, Macaroonman

Comment: The GitHub API is a standard REST API, so any REST client library should do.

Comment: There are many HTTP/REST libraries available for C and C++

Comment: Sorry, I’m a c++ noob. How do you call REST apis?

Comment: Take a look at this: https://github.com/Kicer86/github_api

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to access the Github API with c++?

Yes.

> can't find any c++ libraries

If there is no library, then you need to write the program yourself.

The github API is served through HTTP protocol. C++ has no standard HTTP client. Such client can be written by following the documentation in the RFC's maintained by IETF.

The HTTP communication is going to be over the TCP protocol. C++ has no standard TCP client. You'll find the RFC for TCP also from IETF if needed, but that is unlikely if you run your program on an operating system since the OS will probably provide a TCP API for you. To find find the relevant documentation, you must first know which OS you are targeting.